# How to use Bootstrap in Chrome Extinction Manifest Version 3

Tags: google-chrome, bootstrap-4, google-chrome-extension

I want to use bootstrap in my Chrome Extinction project but Manifest V3 disallows certain CSP modifications for extension_pages that were permitted in Manifest V2. The script-src, object-src, and worker-src directives